# PHP/PDO select data from database with session variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have got the following issue, which I can't seem to solve. I'm using PDO with MySQL in the following function:

```
public function checkST($database) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $ticket = $_SESSION['user']['session_ticket'];
            $check = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_ticket = 'ST-627eed61b0dcc8fe04068e23c9e9ace10fd59cf7-8104' LIMIT 1");         
            $result = $check->fetchColumn();
            var_dump($result);
            if ($result != 1) {
                header('Location: ../?p=login');
            }
        } else {
            header('Location: ../?p=login');
        }
    }


$ticket = $_SESSION['user']['session_ticket'];
            $check = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_ticket = '".$ticket."' LIMIT 1");          
            $result = $check->fetchColumn();
            var_dump($result);
```

returns:

> bool(false)

But when I insert my session ticket like:

```
$ticket = $_SESSION['user']['session_ticket'];
            $check = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_ticket = 'ST-627eed61b0dcc8fe04068e23c9e9ace10fd59cf7-8104' LIMIT 1");         
            $result = $check->fetchColumn();
            var_dump($result);
```

it returns:

```
string(1) "1"
```

which is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear.. however try this:

$check = $database->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_ticket = '.$ticket.' LIMIT 1');

Comment: Whenever possible (most time it is) I go without the double quotes, they are slower than single quotes. Var dump the sql insertion line, we don't see it here, then var dump the select sql also, so we make sure the insert and retrieve the same thing!

Comment: I've actually made a stupid mistake in the title, oops. It shouldn't be inserting, but selecting the user data.

Comment: I've sorted it out. It seemed that I inserted the old session ticket into the session variable instead of the new updated one after the login! Really, I don't have my day.